# Does an Indian national with a USA green card need a visa to visit the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

My mum is a USA green card holder, and has an Indian passport. Does she need a visa to visit me in the UK?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Immigration status in the US is not directly relevant to the need for a UK visitor visa.

A US visa or green card can help someone qualify for *transit* in the UK without a visa, but that is not relevant in this case.

For more information, use [the visa check tool](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) or have a look at [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_United_Kingdom).